# Maximum Likelihood Estimators (Three independent normally distributed values with constraint)

Tags: statistics, optimization, statistical-inference, nonlinear-optimization, maximum-likelihood

The context of the problem is trying to measure the angles between three constellations.

Let $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \theta_{3}$ denote the sizes of its three angles. The measurements of the angles $(X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3})$ are imperfect. Assume they are independently distributed as $N(\theta_{i}, \sigma^2)$, for $i = 1, 2, 3$. Find the maximum likelihood estimators of $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \theta_{3}$ based on his measurements, subject to the constraint $$\theta_{1} + \theta_{2} +  \theta_{3} = 180^{\circ}$$

I understand the general concept of maximum likelihood estimators, but I'm unsure how to work with three non-i.i.d distributions and the equality constraint.

Edit: Based on comments, I have come up with the gradient of the log likelihood function and constraint equation as shown below:

$$  \bigtriangledown  \ell =  \begin{bmatrix}(x_{1} - \theta_{1})/\sigma^2\\(x_{2} - \theta_{2})/\sigma^2 \\ (x_{3} - \theta_{3})/\sigma^2 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda\bigtriangledown  g =  \lambda\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Is this correct? How would I incorporate the constraints that all angles must be greater than 0?

Comment: Independence is enough to write down the joint distribution/likelihood function. Given the sample $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, the likelihood for some constant $c$ is $L(\theta\mid x)=\prod_{i=1}^3 ce^{-(x_i-\theta_i)^2/2\sigma^2}=\cdots$ where $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)\in \mathbb R^3$. As for the constrained optimization, one option is to use (generalized) Lagrange multipliers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions.

Comment: As @StubbornAtom mentioned you'll need to use some constrained optimization routines.  You'll need to use $\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3=180$ (rather than using using "<").  Also replacing $\theta_3$ with $180-\theta_1-\theta_2$ will simplify things along with the constraints that $\theta_1\geq0$ and $\theta_2\geq0$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not very familiar with constrained optimization methods. From what I have gathered, I would take the gradient of the likelihood function (given in the comments) and set it equal to $\lambda$ * gradient of my constraint equation. This will yield a system of equations I solve in order to find the values of theta which maximize my likelihood function, within the boundaries of the constraint. Is this (more or less) correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant take the gradient of the log likelihood function. Is this still permissible in this context? @JimB

Comment: Please add your thoughts/work in the main post, not in comments. And is the constraint $<180^{\circ}$ or $=180^{\circ}$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have update the main post, thank you for letting me know. The constraint is = 180.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to *Mathematica*, here is one approach:

```
(* Some measurments *)
{x1, x2, x3} = {12, 24, 146};

(* Log of the likelihood *)
logL = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[θ1, σ], {x1}] +
  LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[θ2, σ], {x2}] +
  LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[180 - θ1 - θ2, σ], {x3}]
(* -((-12+θ1)^2/(2 σ^2))-(-24+θ2)^2/(2 σ^2)-(-34+θ1+θ2)^2/(2 σ^2)+3/2 (-Log[2]-Log[π])-3 Log[σ] *)

(* Find values that maximize the likelihood subject to the restrictions *)
FindMaximum[{logL, {θ1 + θ2 < 180, θ1 > 0, θ2 > 0}}, {θ1, θ2, σ}]
(* {-3.04042, {θ1 -> 11.3333, θ2 -> 23.3333, σ -> 0.666667}} *)
```

Setting the partial derivatives of $\log L$ to zero and solving for $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $\sigma$ gives one

$$\hat{\theta_1}=(180 + 2 x_1 - x_2 - x_3)/3$$
$$\hat{\theta_2}=(180 - x_1 + 2 x_2 - x_3)/3$$
$$\hat{\sigma} = |180 - x_1 - x_2 - x_3|/3$$

And $\hat{\theta_3}=180-\hat{\theta_1}-\hat{\theta_2}$ or $\hat{\theta_3}=(180-x_1-x_2+2x_3)/3$.  The estimators are weighted estimates of the observed angle and 180 minus the other two angles with weights 2/3 and 1/3, respectively.

Now if the restrictions are all satisfied, then you're done (other than estimating measures of precision).

The variance of $\hat{\theta_i}$ is ${2 \over 3}\sigma^2$ ($i=1,2,3$) and the estimate of the variance from a sample ($x_1, x_2, x_3$) is ${2 \over 27}(x_1+x_2+x_3-180)^2 $.  Note that if the sum of the measured angles is exactly 180, then the estimates of the variance will be zero.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I do not, I'm trying to just solve it analytically.

How does FindMaximum work to incorporate the constraints? Alternatively, what would the resulting system of equations look like if using the Lagrange multiplier method? I'll see what I come up with using that approach.

Comment: @washedupengineer See edit.  Unless the precision of each measurement is large or one angle is huge or very small, I thing the explicit estimators will result in the maximum likelihood estimates.

Comment: should the denominator be 3 or 2 for those expressions? Not sure what I'm messing up in my partials... Must be messing up the algebra somewhere

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that the given solution simply by setting the partial derivatives = 0 cannot be correct, compared to your computed solution (I.e. plugging those values that you used for x1, x2, x3 yields a negative value for angle 2. I will try to proceed using Lagrangian multiples.

Comment: Sorry, I did some cutting-and-pasting followed by the changing of coefficients by hand and forgot to change some of the signs.  I'll fix that.  Note that the solutions are weighted averages of the observed angle and 180 minus the sum of the other two angles with the weights being 2/3 and 1/3, respectively.  Again, sorry for messing up.